# PDFs not rendering from open() in JS

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to have a Google Sankey chart open a PDF for each node; I have it opening a window, but it won't render the PDF. It will pull up a normal webpage, just not render the PDF.

In practice, I'll be computing the url, but I'm just using a test page for now.

I've only implemented this in a fiddle - is there some sort of blocking associated with JSFiddle that could be the issue?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/po4on8om/)

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['sankey']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'From');
  data.addColumn('string', 'To');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
  data.addRows([
    [ 'Geometry', 'Algebra 2', 7 ],
    [ 'Geometry','FST',3],
    [ 'FST','Precalculus',4],
    [ 'FST','Concepts of Adv Math',6],
    [ 'Honors Algebra 2', 'Honors Precalculus', 7 ],
    [ 'Honors Algebra 2', 'Precalculus', 3 ],
    [ 'Algebra', 'Geometry', 7 ],
    [ 'Precalculus','Calculus',8],
    [ 'Precalculus','AP Calculus AB',2],
    [ 'Precalculus','Concepts of Adv Math',2],
    [ 'Honors Precalculus','AP Calculus AB',8],
    [ 'Honors Precalculus','Calculus',2],
    [ 'AP Calculus AB','AP Calculus BC',8],
    [ 'AP Calculus BC','AP Statistics',3],
    [ 'Calculus', 'AP Statistics', 2]


  ]);

  // Sets chart options.
  var options = {
    width: 600,
        tooltip: { isHtml: true },
      sankey: {
          node: {
              interactivity: true,
              nodePadding: 60
          },


      }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    var sel = chart.getSelection();

    if (sel.length) {
        var sel = sel[0].name.replace(/ /g,'');
      //var url = 'http://www.xb.org/images/currtest/'+sel+'.pdf';
      var url = 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf';
      window.open(url);

    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Console errors? Popup blockers?

Comment: No relevant errors, no popup blocking. The new tab opens, with the correct URL in the address bar, but the PDF does not load.

Comment: Does the PDF render when opened from location bar?

Comment: In fact, no amount of reloading of the tab will make it render, but copying and pasting the url into a new tab will load correctly

Comment: Try `http://www.xb.org/images/currtest/'+encodeURIComponent(sel)+'.pdf'`

Comment: This had no effect.

Comment: Looks like it was JSFiddle blocking it; when I put it into a local html document, everything loads fine. Anybody know why?